# React cannot read properties of undefined props

Tags: reactjs

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqkzo.png)

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQgqP.png)

[my object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1mlK.png)

As seen in the images, react says  I cannot access the .title on my object despite the fact that it exists.

When I console log the object after commenting out the JSX it logs the objects meaning it is not an issue with the connection to the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like `bean` is undefined, or maybe it is undefined at one lifecycle of the component.

You can solve it in two ways.
at the beginning of the component, you can add

```
if(!bean) {
  return null;
}
```

Or when you access `bean` do it like this:

```
{bean?.title}
```